# Amazon Cloudwatch Rest API available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest

I have integrated application with amazon cloudwatch using aws .net sdk and now i would like to use it with rest api if available but could not find anything about rest api available for cloudwatch , can anyone please suggest me some link for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Watch Api Actions GetMetricStatistics](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html)